# PanGestureRecognizer ломает вертикальный скрол tableView

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

Добавляю к каждой ячейке обработчик жеста pan, но после этого не работает
скрол для tableView.

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

func panHandler(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = pan.translation(in: self.view)
    let view = pan.view

    if pan.state == .began {
        print("Start!")
    }
    if pan.state == .changed {
        view!.center = CGPoint(x: (view?.center.x)! + point.x, y: (view?.center.y)!)
        pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
    if pan.state == .ended {
        print("Ended!")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            pan.view?.center.x = self.view.center.x
            pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        })
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Исправил добавлением строки после объявления константы pan

```
pan.delegate = self
```